# meijer G parameters of common functions

Tags: math-software

I'm trying to understand how a Meijer G function changes in parameters when I change the function a little bit. For example, I know that the meijer G parameters of the following functions
\begin{aligned}
 \cos x=\sqrt{\pi} G_{0,2}^{1,0}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
- & x^2 \\
0, \frac{1}{2} & \frac{-\pi}{4}
\end{array}\right), \quad \forall x
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
 \sin x=\sqrt{\pi} G_{0,2}^{1,0}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
- & x^2 \\
\frac{1}{2}, 0 & \frac{-\pi}{4}
\end{array}\right), \quad -\frac\pi2\leq \arg x \leq \frac\pi2
\end{aligned}

But I want to be able to ask like what is the meijer G parameters function of $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ (and other simple combinations of elementary functions as well. Does anyone know a good lookup table or software that will allow me to do that?

Comment: Python library mpmath

Comment: Based on this documentation https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html the meijerg() functions takes in mejer G functions parameters as in puts and spits out the elementary function. What I'm looking for is the reverse of that.